# Applying Fluid CSS to a Relative Div within a Centered Div with Absolute Images

Tags: html, css, css-position

WHat I'm trying to do is create a layout that utilises the best of fluid resizing and absolute positioning at the same time.

What I have is a set size centered div, within it I have absolute images the width of the div, and below those images I have a legend.  Now I have the images resizing when the window is shrunk, but I cannot get the behaviour on the legend correct.  What I want to happen is that when I resize the window, the legend shrinks accordingly and is always below the images, but never overlaps.  And for the life of me I cannot solve this.

Code is as follows (you can also view at jsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Sonictail/2cms6/1/);

### css

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#container {
    position:relative;
    min-width: 640px;
    max-width: 1044px;
    max-height: 200px;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    background-color:red;
    z-index:0;
}
#shim {
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    min-width:640px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
#legend {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    min-width:640px;
    max-width:1024px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:blue;
    z-index:20;
}
img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    min-width:640px;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color:green;
    float:left;
    z-index:1;
}
```

### html

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="map">
        <img src="image.png" />
        <img src="image.png" />
    </div>
    <div id="shim">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="legend">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc viverra, est tempor rhoncus dapibus, elit tellus convallis enim, ac ornare felis diam eget velit. Proin a lorem erat. Nulla orci tortor, ornare et erat consequat, porttitor mattis purus. Vestibulum at neque quis neque elementum egestas quis non magna. Aenean porttitor arcu mattis urna sollicitudin, non euismod mauris consequat. In magna erat, viverra vitae urna convallis, sodales lobortis nibh. Quisque suscipit tincidunt lacus, id varius nunc lacinia sed. Proin at nunc consectetur, tincidunt ligula non, bibendum nisl. Suspendisse euismod ac metus vel posuere. Praesent ipsum risus, pellentesque in lectus adipiscing, egestas faucibus risus. Aliquam volutpat odio id pulvinar scelerisque. Maecenas convallis eleifend ante, non feugiat odio viverra nec.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First off. No offence, but your code is a mess. You don't use `bottom: 0;` and `left: 0;` with relative positioning. And there is no need for adding `max` and `min` `width` to every element in the code. It's enough to add it once to the main container. Everything else should be `width: 100%;`. **A question for you, the `#legend` goes below the image, correct? Cause in the code above you are using `z-index: 20;` that would place it way above. And also, what are you trying to achieve with the `max-height: 200px;` tag?**

Comment: Also, could I please get a screen shot of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I suggest you to learn a little bit about the css positioning. There are very few good docs about this on the net, sorry :-( But simple try - and test won't work, AFAIK this time you should learn a little bit, too.

Answer (score 0):

What I was trying to do is have a relative div resize in the same manner as an absolute div using min/max-width & height without using jQuery.  The absolute images over the top stuffed everything around.

I gave it all in.  You can view the jsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Sonictail/rd3eq/1/ and the js I used to modify the height is below.  Nothing fancy.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    resizeDiv();
});

var resizeTimer;
jQuery(window).resize(function ($) {
    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(resizeDiv, 100);

});

var resizeDiv = function () {
    var img = document.getElementById('mapHeight');

    var height = img.clientHeight;

    jQuery("#shim").css("height", height);
};
```